# How to serialize multiple files in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to serialize multiple files, send the files using 'Postman' and have tried several ways to save several files at once.

This is the model:

```
class PrtFiles(models.Model):
    file_name = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
```

And I getting this request in my view in Django:

```
<MultiValueDict: {'file_name[0]': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: Inventario Personal_Users [SHORT].xlsx (application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet)>], 'file_name[1]': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: Planilla_de_Usuarios_MEL [NEW][SHORT].xlsx (application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet)>]}>
```

Whit this Request in Postman:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxZr9.png)

Any method that to do that?

P.S. I'm beginner with Django, thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the files where you can see the request.

```
def save_to_model(files):
  for f in files:
    m = PrtFiles()
    m.file_name = f
    m.save()
```

**This is the idea what you can do it. I hope you'll implement a better way.**